# Can QLDB be used to atomically increment an attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

The use-case is to keep track of exact number of items in a warehouse.

The warehouse has incoming items from multiple customer and the warehouse has to keep track of the item count per customer so that the warehouse owner knows the accurate count of items per customer.

So, if we were to use a QLDB to increment `item_count` per `customer_id` as and when they enter teh warehouse, would the QLDB be able to handle multi-item transaction?

If there was a read, write inconsistency, would the write to QLDB fail? We want the writes to be consistent but we are okay to read T1's data if the current data is at T2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

QLDB supports transactions under [OCC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/concurrency.html). Each transaction can have multiple statements. These statements can query the current state of the ledger to determine if the transaction can proceed. If it can, keep issuing statements until you are ready to commit. Your commit will be rejected if any other transaction interfered with it (the transaction must be serializable).

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense that one of the interfering transactions will fail to commit. Say, I overcame the interfering transaction issue with Kinesis Analytics  (ie) Kinesis Analytics is used to aggregate the count per customerid for every small interval and then have a lambda to put the write to QLDB, would this be a good use-case for QLDB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "overcame the interfering transaction issue", but the second part sounds right :)